# SQL Server : view returns weird extra row

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server view which returns 1 row for this query:

```
select * 
from [dbo].[MyView] v 
where v.ProductID = 38
```

but returns an extra (wrong) row for this query:

```
select * 
from [dbo].[MyView] v 
where v.ProductID = 38 and 1 != 2
```

and an extra (wrong) row for this query:

```
select top 10 * 
from [dbo].[MyView] v 
where v.ProductID = 38
```

I'm wondering why adding a truthy predicate makes the view return an extra row. I'm sure it's not related to the contents of the view hence why I've not said what's in it (none of my columns are called 1 or 2 by the way!)

Comment: How many rows in total and what is the content of that two rows? You say that it doesn't matter, but then `and 1 != 2` should always cause an extra row which is definitely not true.

Comment: yep, if it was just the '1 != 2' in my list of predicates then i'd obviously expect all rows back but its only in combination of the other 'v.productid = 38' that I get the extra row

Comment: Try running sp_refreshview

Comment: share your table data !

Comment: tried sp_refreshview but it didn't help.  Hmmm having changed the logic in the view this problem no longer occurs.  So that suggests the logic was responsible after all.  It still strikes me as odd how this occurred though.

Comment: Please post source data and the returned result along with script of VIEW